# Can't use last element of array in a conditional?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

A weird thing is happening, i must be missing something but the code bellow doesn't work as expected:

```
  const operators = /([-+/*])/g;

  let operatorsArray = ['1','/', '*'];

  operatorsArray = operatorsArray.filter(element => element !== '');

  console.log(operators.test(operatorsArray[operatorsArray.length - 1])); //returns true

  if (operators.test(operatorsArray[operatorsArray.length - 1])) {
    console.log("I'm in!!"); //doesn't log
  }
```

As comment in the code, for some reason the `if` doesn't run.

Comment: Don't use the global flag unless you actually need it

Comment: That worked, thanks for answering and linking the other question. Didn't know about the regex index when using the global flag